# PHP: How to set lat and long of center Google Map from database?

Tags: php, sql, google-maps

How can I set the center of a map based on a latitude and longitude retrieved from my database?

I'm trying to connect $lat and $lon in the script below to the latitude and longitude values in my database.

My attribute latitude and longitude are stored in the database as lat and lon.

this is my code :

```
function initialize2() 
  {
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng($lat,$lon);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 17,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE 
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the file compile as a php script? In other words does it end with a .php extension or .js? If its .php you should enclose the variables in php tags like so:

```
function initialize2() 
{
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat . ',' . $lon; ?>);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE 
};
```

If its a .js script you cannot include PHP variables like that, as it does not compile with PHP